# Cancelling Python Script Tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-script-tool

I am trying to let a user cancel the ArcToolbox script tool that I am creating. When the code is running, if I press cancel, the process just continues. I have looked at ESRI help on the issue (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/understanding-cancellation-behavior-in-script-tools.htm) but I cannot get the tool to respond to the cancel command mid run.

I have tried both autoCancelling = true and false with various states of isCancelled both in and out of if statements.

What am I missing?

ArcpMap 10.3 python2.7

This is my attempt to date:

```
import arcpy, time
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.autoCancelling = False

    if x == 1:
        arcpy.AddError('A landbase with this name already exists, you have 10s to cancel otherwise it will be overwritted')
        timing = 1
        while timing < 11:
            time.sleep(1)
            arcpy.AddMessage(str(timing))
            timing += 1
            if arcpy.env.isCancelled == True:
                sys.exit()
```

Comment: You are referring to ArcGIS Pro documentation when you have an ArcGIS Desktop issue. It may or may not apply so I think you should look for equivalent documentation on the older architecture.

Comment: Progress bar usually works for me

Answer (score 1):

I think @PolyGeo has hit the nail on the head here, you are using 10.3, this is functionality that is only available in 10.4 onward. If you look at the help file [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/analyze/creating-tools/understanding-cancellation-behavior-in-script-tools.htm#) only 10.5 and 10.4 are available under the *Other Versions* drop down.

Comment: so, how do I let the user cancel?

Comment: Not sure you can, happy to be proven wrong!